# How to let python know where a certain library is?

Tags: python, llvm

I compiled and installed LLVM from source to an arbitrary path: `/arbitrary/path/llvm`. I then compiled and installed a package that has a python module, and needs the LLVM libraries. When I try to import the module:

```
>>> import module_name
```

I'm getting the error:

```
ImportError: libLLVM-14.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I was told to add the location where I installed LLVM to my library search path. I'm not entirely sure what this means. I have tried three things, all of which have failed:

```
$PATH=$PATH:/arbitrary/path/llvm/bin:/arbitrary/path/llvm/lib
```

and

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path.append('/arbitrary/path/llvm/bin')
>>> sys.path.append('/arbitrary/path/llvm/lib')
```

and

```
export PYTHONPATH=${PYTHONPATH}:/arbitrary/path/llvm/bin:/arbitrary/path/llvm/lib
```

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious, but I can't find what it is.

Comment: For a dynamic library: `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=...`. If on macOS, use `export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=...` instead.

Comment: Be careful putting this directly into Python code, like you tried with `sys.path.append`. It's better to set it in your environment, because that is where the the directory system is found. Potentially in a .bashrc or .zshrc or similar file.

Comment: You write `import module_name`, but the error shows `libLLVM-14.so`. Is the package you are importing really called `module_name`?

Comment: Why not copy it into the appropriate subdirectory of `/usr/local/lib` so it can be used by other apps as well?

Comment: @TimRoberts I'm in an HPC setting where I don't have write access.

Comment: @9769953 `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` did it -- thanks!

`module_name` is a module that needs llvm libraries.

Comment: Yes, but it helps if you don't alter names (or shorten errors; I think the actual error is longer?), because that will cause confusing and (incorrect) guesses at parts left out.

Comment: I see.  `sys.path` only works for finding Python modules.  It doesn't help for C libraries.  The first comment is the right one, using the library path environment variables.